# Can Model A has_one Model B that has_and_belongs_to_many Model A?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's an example of what I currently have in place:

```
#app/models/company.rb
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :platform
end
```

.

```
#app.models/platform.rb
class Platform < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
end
```

and I also have a migration that created a join table to link a platform with multiple companies

```
class CreateJoinTableCompanyPlatforms < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_join_table :companies, :platforms do |t|
      t.index [:company_id, :platform_id]
      t.index [:platform_id, :company_id]
    end
  end
end
```

However, when I go to my view and I try to call `Company.first.platform`, I get this error:

> ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column
>   'platforms.company_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `platforms`.* FROM
>   `platforms` WHERE `platforms`.`company_id` = 1 LIMIT 1):

Is there an issue with my joins table, or can I not construct my models like this?

If I change my `has_one :platform` to `has_and_belongs_to_many :platforms` then it works perfectly, so I've gotta be missing something or this might just not be the best way to do it.

My reason for using a `has_one` was because every time I call `company`, I didn't want to have to specify `company.platforms.first.name` and would rather just do `company.platform.name` since it should only have one anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`has_and_belongs_to_many` is intended to be used symmetrically; in other words, if the Platform model uses it to point to Company, then the Company model should use it to point to Platform. Trying to pair it with another type of association should fail, and is failing.

If you want `company.platform.name` to work, have you considered the `has_many` relationship? Like this:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :platform
end

class Platform < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :companies
end
```

This type of relationship does not need a join table. Instead it uses the `platform.company_id` column mentioned in your error message.

Comment: Hmm, this is a very interesting way to go about it. I haven't thought about doing it this way, but I thinks this might actually work for me. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to hear it! It's worth knowing that `has_and_belongs_to_many` is intended as a many-to-many relationship. But, if each company is concerned with only one platform, yet a platform is concerned with more than one company, that is instead a one-to-many relationship. Finally, `has_one` is intended as a one-to-one relationship, which is very infrequently used. I find myself using one-to-many relationships the most.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Much appreciated

Comment: Oh, and if this ends up working out for you, please check it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
rails g scaffold Platform name
rails g scaffold Company name platform:references
```

## Edit models with inverse_of

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :platform, inverse_of: companies
end

class Platform < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :companies, inverse_of: platform
end
```

## Create the platform and the company

```
Platform.create({name: 'pl47'})
Company.create({name: 'My Company', platform: Platform.first })
Company.create({name: 'Your Company', platform: Platform.first })
```

## Now you can use:

```
Company.first.platform
Company.first.platform.name
Platform.find(1).companies
Platform.find(1).companies.each do |company|
  puts company.name
end
```

Comment: This is actually very interesting as well. Quick question, is there a benefit to doing it this way vs without using `inverse_of` (like the other answer)? Learn something new every day! :)

Comment: From the documentation, it seems like the :inverse_of option is a method for avoiding SQL queries, not generating them. It's a hint to ActiveRecord to use already loaded data instead of fetching it again through a relationship.

Comment: Thanks so much. I did try the first solution, but I really appreciate the help on this. I'll definitely keep this handy.